# I need an earthquake early warning system

Tags: warnings, system, real-time, faker

I'm working on an earthquake early warning system. some one told me

> I had found a similar solution in
>   http://remotegun.com/earthquake-early-warning-system/

but I couldn't find anything online. also I couldn't get answer from by mail.
Thing I need are methods people could seduce these systems.
Do you have any idea? or are you familiar with guys in remotegun.com?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's based on the idea of the 'twitter wave' that occurs when an large scale event is noticed by someone using twitter. They put the message onto twitter and it travels at near the speed of light. This can get to other people faster than the speed of sound that (for example) the earthquake itself travels through the ground.

Sound in AIR travels at about 5 seconds per mile and earthquake waves are quicker so there isn't much time.